# How to open a custom scheme in android with java

Tags: java, android, oauth, custom-url-protocol

I'm using this OAuth library https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android
I've registered a custom scheme

```
    <activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="kronos"
                  android:host="oauth2"/> <!-- Redirect URI scheme -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I've those methods:

```
private void authorize() {

    AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            mServiceConfiguration,
            "...", // Client ID
            ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
            Uri.parse("kronos://oauth2/callback") // Redirect URI
    ).setScope("auth").build();


    AuthorizationService service = new AuthorizationService(this);

    Intent intent = service.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(authRequest);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTH);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTH) {
        Log.d(TAG, "get the token");
        return;
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "wrong code");
        return;
}
```

It works fine but now I want to handle a custom URL like, for example, "kronos://something", so here is 2 questions so far:

-can the handling be done in onActivityResult and how?

-can I call this custom protocol in chrome to test (like in iOS with safari)?

Edit:To be more precise what I receive is a custom URL when user logout in order to delete OAuth token

**EDIT2**
I've added that in the manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".activity_logoff">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="kronos"
                android:host="something"/> <!-- Redirect URI scheme -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I don't know how to make the app intercepting all url "kronos://something"

**EDIT3**
I've now create the Intent that may be needed

```
Uri logoutUri = Uri.parse("kronos://something");
Intent logoutIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,logoutUri);
```

**EDIT4**
I've added

```
    logoutIntent1.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

But what to do next

Answer (score 0):

What do you want this `kronos://something` for? Does it have anything with authentication response? If not, then oAuth has nothing to do here.

You're close with declaring activity_logoff. All you need to do is to call:
`context.startActivity(logoutIntent1)` - where context can be any Activity.